# Postgresql materialized view is refreshed by itself

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have this materialized view in my Postgres 9.4 database:

```
                 Materialized view "public.v_videolist"
  Column  |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
----------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id       | integer |           | plain    |              |
 title    | text    |           | extended |              |
 embed    | text    |           | extended |              |
 img      | text    |           | extended |              |
 imgs     | text    |           | extended |              |
 tags     | text    |           | extended |              |
 category | text    |           | extended |              |
 vid      | bigint  |           | plain    |              |
 views    | bigint  |           | plain    |              |
 likes    | bigint  |           | plain    |              |
 unlikes  | bigint  |           | plain    |              |
 duration | integer |           | plain    |              |
 site     | integer |           | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "i_vl_id" UNIQUE, btree (id)
View definition:
 SELECT videolist.id,
    videolist.title,
    videolist.embed,
    videolist.img,
    videolist.imgs,
    videolist.tags,
    videolist.category,
    videolist.vid,
    videolist.views,
    videolist.likes,
    videolist.unlikes,
    videolist.duration,
    videolist.site
   FROM videolist
  ORDER BY random();
```

Time to time this view refreshed by itself. There is no cron job to refresh it or something like that. It is just refreshed by itself from time to time, and I can't find who does it. I fully log all queries. There is no any `refresh materialized view` in the log.

Why is my view renewed? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A job could be scheduled to update the statistics  using this SQL statement:

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW public.v_videolist;
```

You can use `pg_cron` to schedule the job.